# How much a UIImageView rotated?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have an UIImageView that is being pinched, zoomed, rotated, etc. When the user ends transforming the image he presses the DONE button and I have to figure out how much the object was scaled and rotated.

All I know is the angle and scale of the object before the user started modifying it. Now I need the new angle and scale.

How to do that? If you can point to a code, it will help.

thanks

Comment: This is the same as [another question you asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379811/obtaining-the-rotation-and-size-of-a-uiimageview-based-on-its-transformation-matr/1395787) - see my answer to that question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to keep a track of all changes made.
If the user pinches zooms,etc, it means that the app will calculate the rotation and zooming for every touch the user does right?
So, Why don't use the last touch to know the rotation and zoom? 
You could update your zoom and rotation variable every time the user does a touch. 
Regards
Ignacio