# iPhone: How to use CGContextConcatCTM for saving a transformed image properly?

Tags: iphone, matrix, uiimageview, transform, cgcontext

I am making an iPhone application that loads an image from the camera, and then the user can select a second image from the library, move/scale/rotate that second image, and then save the result. I use two UIImageViews in IB as placeholders, and then apply transformations while touching/pinching.

The problem comes when I have to save both images together. I use a rect of the size of the first image and pass it to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`. Then I tried to use `CGContextConcatCTM` but I can't understand how it works:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, img1.size.width, img1.size.height); // img1 from camera
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size); // Start drawing
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextClearRect(ctx, rect); // Clear whole thing
[img1 drawAtPoint:CGPointZero]; // Draw background image at 0,0
CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, img2.transform); // Apply the transformations of the 2nd image
```

But what do I need to do next? What information is being held in the img2.transform matrix? The documentation for `CGContextConcatCTM` doesn't help me that much unfortunately..
Right now I'm trying to solve it by calculating the points and the angle using trigonometry (with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379811/obtaining-the-rotation-and-size-of-a-uiimageview-based-on-its-transformation-matr)), but since the transformation is there, there has to be an easier and more elgant way to do this, right?

Comment: I guess the problem is that Quartz applies transformation from the upper-left corner :/ I still do not know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this excellent answer, you need to create a bitmapped/image context, draw to it, and get the resultant image out. You can then save that. [iOS UIImagePickerController result image orientation after upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427656/ios-uiimagepickercontroller-result-image-orientation-after-upload/5427890#5427890)