# NSData from UIImage. Uploading to server with wrong orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsdata

I'm trying to upload `UIImage` which taken from `UIImagePickerController` using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`. But it shows on server with wrong orientation. First of all, I'd like to ask is there way to fix it on my side? Or if not how to handle it on server?

I already saw [iOS 4 Image Oriented Incorrectly When Posted To Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380376/ios-4-image-oriented-incorrectly-when-posted-to-server) and this one [Save UIImage, Load it in Wrong Orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838699/save-uiimage-load-it-in-wrong-orientation) but I need to show image with right orientation directly on server not in application.

Comment: Have a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427656/ios-uiimagepickercontroller-result-image-orientation-after-upload/5427890#5427890
It might help you to fix image orientation.

Comment: @VincentZgueb it can help if I want to show image in imageView but orientation changes in moment when I convert it to NSData and send to a server. In moment when we picking image from picker orientation is right.

Comment: I have the exact same problem… Did you arrive to a solution?

Answer (score 1):

From what I've found, this seems to be the best answer.
[iOS UIImagePickerController result image orientation after upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427656/ios-uiimagepickercontroller-result-image-orientation-after-upload/5427890#5427890)

Add the category UIImage+fixOrientation to your project and import "UIImage+fixOrientation.h" in your view controller.

Then you should be able to use something like this.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    image = [image fixOrientation];

    NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);

}
```

Comment: No :( Because orientation changes in moment when we convert `UIImage` to `NSData` not when we picking it.

Comment: Have you tried this specifically? Orientation change is not caused by converting it to NSData. The original image returned from the image picker only has orientation stored as exif data, this code rotates the image itself.

Answer (score 0):

try

`UIImage *orientationFixedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[originalImage CGImage] scale:1.0 orientation:originalImage.imageOrientation];`