# OpenCV in XCode -cmake error

Tags: xcode, opencv

I'm on a mac 10.7.5 trying to work with the OpenCV library in XCode 4.6.2.  I'm following this tutorial http://sadeepj.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/installing-and-configuring-opencv-to.html

So I've downloaded cmake and OpenCV2.3.1 I have written in terminal :

```
tar xvf OpenCV-2.3.1a.tar.bz2 
cd OpenCV-2.3.1 
mkdir build 
cd build 
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..
```

It all works except at the `Unix Makefiles` command, where it says `CMake Error: Could not create named generator Unix Makefiles..`

Anyone know why this is happening or maybe there is another method of getting OpenCV running smoothly in Xcode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I encourage you to avoid compiling OpenCV by yourself, whenever possible.

You can download the latest OpenCV compiled framework for iOS [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-ios/2.4.6/opencv2.framework.zip/download), and [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-ios/) you can find some previous versions. To use the framework, just drag the `opencv2.framework` directory to your XCode project, and you're done.

Comment: Thanks so much! I've written #include "cv.h" but is this no longer used in opencv2?

Comment: No problem :)
You need to `#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>` instead (and I recommend to use the C++ interface instead the old C one). Since the headers are pretty big, I recommend to put the `#import` in the pch file surrounded by `#ifdef __cplusplus ... #endif`.

Comment: One more question sorry. I'm getting an error about missing architecture in my framework "missing required architecture x86_64 in file ..." and about 14 errors like this: _cvShowImage", referenced from: _main in File.o.    I've changed my compiler aswell to GCC

Comment: You cannot use highgui functions (such as `cvShowImage`) with iOS. Actually, IIRC all the image loading should be done via `UIImage` or `CGImage`, and then to OpenCV's `cv::Mat`. To display an image, you need to convert your `cv::Mat` to `UIImage`. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254141/how-to-convert-from-cvmat-to-uiimage-in-objective-c) is a conversion example.