# How to convert opencv cv::Mat to CVPixelBuffer

Tags: ios, opencv, coreml

I'm an undergraduate student and I'm doing some HumanSeg iPhone app using `CoreML`. Since my model needs ***resizing and black padding*** on the original video frames, I can't rely on `Vision` (which only provides resizing but no black padding) and have to do the converting myself.

I have `CVPixelBuffer` frames and I have converted it into `cv::Mat` using the following codes:

```
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
int bufferWidth = (int) CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer);
int bufferHeight = (int) CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer);
int bytePerRow = (int) CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer);
unsigned char *pixel = (unsigned char *) CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer);
Mat image = Mat(bufferHeight, bufferWidth, CV_8UC4, pixel, bytePerRow);
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
/*I'll do my resizing and padding here*/

// How can I implement this function?
convertToCVPixelBuffer(image);
```

But now, after I've done my preprocessing works, I have to ***convert*** the `cv::Mat` ***back to*** a `CVPixelBuffer` to feed it to the `CoreML` model. How can I achieve this? (Or can Vision achieve black padding using some special techniques?)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please see below the code... Checking whether width and height is divisible by 64 is necessary or else we get weird results due to `BytesPerRow` mismatch with `cv::Mat` and `CVPixelBuffer`

```
CVPixelBufferRef getImageBufferFromMat(cv::Mat matimg) {
    cv::cvtColor(matimg, matimg, CV_BGR2BGRA);
    
    /* Very much required see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66434552/objective-c-cvmat-to-cvpixelbuffer
     height & width has to be multiple of 64 for better caching
     */
    int widthReminder = matimg.cols % 64, heightReminder = matimg.rows % 64;
    if (widthReminder != 0 || heightReminder != 0) {
        cv::resize(matimg, matimg, cv::Size(matimg.cols + (64 - widthReminder), matimg.rows + (64 - heightReminder)));
    }
    
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
                             [NSNumber numberWithInt: matimg.cols], kCVPixelBufferWidthKey,
                             [NSNumber numberWithInt: matimg.rows], kCVPixelBufferHeightKey,
                             [NSNumber numberWithInt: matimg.step[0]], kCVPixelBufferBytesPerRowAlignmentKey,
                             nil];
    CVPixelBufferRef imageBuffer;
    CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorMalloc, matimg.cols, matimg.rows, kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, (CFDictionaryRef) CFBridgingRetain(options), &imageBuffer) ;
    NSParameterAssert(status == kCVReturnSuccess && imageBuffer != NULL);
    
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);
    void *base = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
    memcpy(base, matimg.data, matimg.total() * matimg.elemSize());
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);
    
    return imageBuffer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, convert mat to UIImage (or any other class from iOS APIs), check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254141/how-to-convert-from-cvmat-to-uiimage-in-objective-c). Then, convert resulting image to `CVPixelBuffer` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44400741/convert-image-to-cvpixelbuffer-for-machine-learning-swift).

Comment: Thanks to your help, but this method is way too slow and is insufferable for a video process app.

Answer (score 0):

For people who will be using the new OpenCV Swift Wrapper, here is @Abhinava 's code translated to Swift

```
func matToCVPixelBuffer(mat: Mat)-> CVPixelBuffer? {
    let matrix = Mat()
    Imgproc.cvtColor(src: mat, dst: matrix, code: ColorConversionCodes.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
    
    let widthRemainder = matrix.cols() % 64
    let heightRemainder = matrix.rows() % 64
    
    if widthRemainder != 0 || heightRemainder != 0 {
        Imgproc.resize(src: matrix, dst: matrix, dsize: Size(width: matrix.cols() + (64 - widthRemainder), height: matrix.rows() + (64 - heightRemainder)))
    }
    
    let attributes = [
        kCVPixelBufferMetalCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue!,
        kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue!,
        kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue!,
        kCVPixelBufferWidthKey: matrix.cols(),
        kCVPixelBufferHeightKey: matrix.rows(),
        kCVPixelBufferBytesPerRowAlignmentKey: matrix.step1(0)
    ] as CFDictionary
    
    var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?
    
    let status = CVPixelBufferCreate(
        kCFAllocatorDefault, Int(matrix.cols()),
        Int(matrix.rows()),
        kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA,
        attributes,
        &pixelBuffer)
    
    guard let pixelBuffer = pixelBuffer, (status == kCVReturnSuccess) else {
        return nil
    }
    
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
    
    let base = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer)
    memcpy(base, matrix.dataPointer(), matrix.total()*matrix.elemSize())
    
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
    
    return pixelBuffer
}
```