# How to rotate an image 90 degrees on iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, rotation

What I want to do is take a snapshot from my camera , send it to a server and then the server sends me back the image on a viewController. If the image is in portrait mode the image appears well on screen , however if the image was taken in landscape mode the image appears streched on the screen(as it tries to appear on portrait mode!). I dont know how to fix this but i guess one solution is first to check if the image is in portrait/landscape mode and then if it is on landscape mode rotate it by 90degrees before showing it on screen.
So how could i do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS UIImagePickerController result image orientation after upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427656/ios-uiimagepickercontroller-result-image-orientation-after-upload)

Comment: I had the exact same problem and I solved it using the category proposed in this response : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5427890/1327557
It manage all cases (rotations and miroring)

Answer (score 128, accepted):

```
self.imageview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
```

**Swift 4+:**

```
self.imageview.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi/2))
```

Comment: Isn't `M_PI/2` going to cause an unwanted type casting into an int and subsequent loss of accuracy?

Comment: I found that this rotated my image 45 degrees when using on a regular view

Comment: 'Double' is not convertible to 'CGFloat' - I got this error
    cell.arrowImageView?.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2))    - force type cast fix

Answer (score 30):

This is the complete code for rotation of image to any degree just add it to appropriate file ie in .m as below where you want to use the image processing

**for .m**

```
@interface UIImage (RotationMethods)
- (UIImage *)imageRotatedByDegrees:(CGFloat)degrees;
@end

@implementation UIImage (RotationMethods)

static CGFloat DegreesToRadians(CGFloat degrees) {return degrees * M_PI / 180;};

- (UIImage *)imageRotatedByDegrees:(CGFloat)degrees 
{   
    // calculate the size of the rotated view's containing box for our drawing space
    UIView *rotatedViewBox = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.width, self.size.height)];
    CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(degrees));
    rotatedViewBox.transform = t;
    CGSize rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size;

    // Create the bitmap context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize);
    CGContextRef bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
    CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, rotatedSize.width/2, rotatedSize.height/2);

    //   // Rotate the image context
    CGContextRotateCTM(bitmap, DegreesToRadians(degrees));

    // Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
    CGContextScaleCTM(bitmap, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(-self.size.width / 2, -self.size.height / 2, self.size.width, self.size.height), [self CGImage]);

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;

}

@end
```

This is the code snippet form apple's [SquareCam](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SquareCam/Listings/SquareCam_SqareCamViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011190-SquareCam_SqareCamViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_4) example.

To call the above method just use the below code

```
UIImage *rotatedSquareImage = [square imageRotatedByDegrees:rotationDegrees];
```

Here the **square** is one `UIImage` and **rotationDegrees** is one `flote` ivar to rotate the image that degrees

Comment: this code does not work for portrait mode image for first time.

Comment: For the above code to work, you also need to add:  

static CGFloat DegreesToRadians(CGFloat degrees) {return degrees * M_PI / 180;};

Comment: @Vishu As I know it taking memory respective to image size and after done it released the occupied memory

Answer (score 23):

Swift 3 and Swift 4 use .pi instead

eg:

```
//rotate 90 degrees
myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi / 2)

//rotate 180 degrees
myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi)

//rotate 270 degrees
myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi * 1.5)
```

Comment: how do i change to direction of the rotation?

Comment: @BenShabat pass in a negative value.

Answer (score 14):

```
- (UIImage *)rotateImage:(UIImage*)image byDegree:(CGFloat)degrees 
{   
    UIView *rotatedViewBox = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width, image.size.height)];
    CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(degrees));
    rotatedViewBox.transform = t;
    CGSize rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size;
    [rotatedViewBox release];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize);
    CGContextRef bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, rotatedSize.width, rotatedSize.height);

    CGContextRotateCTM(bitmap, DegreesToRadians(degrees));


    CGContextScaleCTM(bitmap, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(-image.size.width, -image.size.height, image.size.width, image.size.height), [image CGImage]);

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;

}
```

Comment: This answer lowers image resolution, if image has scale factor. Besides that this is a great answer. Add next code and use width and height variables instead of image.size.width and image.size.height: CGFloat width = image.size.width * image.scale, height = image.size.height * image.scale;

Comment: Or easier, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rotatedSize, NO, image.scale) instead of UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()

Answer (score 8):

Simply add this code to the image.

```
Image.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2);
```

Answer (score 6):

I got an error trying this in XCode 6.3 Swift 1.2

```
self.imageview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
```

You should try this to force type cast fix:

```
self.imageview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2));
```

**Swift 4 Edit**

```
imageview.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi/2)
```

Comment: I think it should be pi/2

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3 version:

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(M_PI_2))
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4+.**

```
arrowImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi/2)
```

[Note: angle is in radian](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgaffinetransform/1455666-init)

> .pi = 180 degree
>
> .pi/2 = 90 degree

If you want to add with animation

```
  @IBAction func applyTransForm(sender: UIButton) {
        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
        if sender.isSelected {
            self.arrowImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi)
        } else {
            self.arrowImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 0)

        }
        })
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4 | Xcode 9 syntax** (please note that this code rotates a UIImageView 90 degrees clockwise, not a UIImage):

```
myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 func imageRotatedByDegrees(oldImage: UIImage, deg degrees: CGFloat) -> UIImage {

    let size = oldImage.size
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)

    let bitmap: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    //Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
    bitmap.translateBy(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2)
    //Rotate the image context
    bitmap.rotate(by: (degrees * CGFloat(Double.pi / 180)))
    //Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
    bitmap.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

    let origin = CGPoint(x: -size.width / 2, y: -size.width / 2)

    bitmap.draw(oldImage.cgImage!, in: CGRect(origin: origin, size: size))

    let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage

}
```

Use of function

```
imageRotatedByDegrees(oldImage: yourImage, deg: degree)
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing it in the `Image` Level, in ***Swift 5***:

```
extension UIImage{
    
    
    func imageRotated(by radian: CGFloat) -> UIImage{
        
        let rotatedSize = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
            .applying(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: radian))
            .integral.size
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize)
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            let origin = CGPoint(x: rotatedSize.width / 2.0,
                                 y: rotatedSize.height / 2.0)
            context.translateBy(x: origin.x, y: origin.y)
            context.rotate(by: radian)
            draw(in: CGRect(x: -origin.y, y: -origin.x,
                            width: size.width, height: size.height))
            let rotatedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

            return rotatedImage ?? self
        }

        return self

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Swift 2.2 version of The iOSDev answer (in UIImage extension):

```
func degreesToRadians(degrees: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return degrees * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180
}

func imageRotatedByDegrees(degrees: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    // calculate the size of the rotated view's containing box for our drawing space
    let rotatedViewBox = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.width, self.size.height))
    let t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(self.degreesToRadians(degrees))
    rotatedViewBox.transform = t
    let rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size

    // Create the bitmap context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize)
    let bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    // Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
    CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, rotatedSize.width/2, rotatedSize.height/2);

    // Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
    CGContextScaleCTM(bitmap, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(-self.size.width / 2, -self.size.height / 2, self.size.width, self.size.height), self.CGImage);

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It´s best only use the bitmap. In my case use a UIImage that is in reference.image and I converted image at base64String. Without CGAffineTransformMakeRotation and without rotatedViewBox.transform

```
var rotatedSize = reference.image.size;
                //Create bitmap context
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize);
                var bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
                //move origin to the middle of the image for rotation
                CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, rotatedSize.width / 2, rotatedSize.height / 2);
                //rotate image context
                CGContextRotateCTM(bitmap, 1.5708);
                CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(-reference.image.size.width / 2, -reference.image.size.height / 2, reference.image.size.width, reference.image.size.height), reference.image.CGImage);
                var rotatedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                var base64Image = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(rotatedImage, compression).base64EncodedStringWithOptions(0);
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
                return base64Image;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to save image then you need to rotate picture context not the view. I have used provided examples above but they did not work well when centering the image. So I have enhanced and fixed as follows :

```
func imageRotatedByDegrees(deg degrees: CGFloat) -> UIImage {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: self.size.height, height: self.size.width))

    let bitmap: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

    // Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
    bitmap.translateBy(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height / 2)

    // Rotate the image context
    bitmap.rotate(by: (degrees * CGFloat(Double.pi / 180)))

    // Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
    bitmap.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

    let origin = CGPoint(x: -self.size.height / 2, y: -self.size.width / 2)

    bitmap.draw(self.cgImage!, in: CGRect(origin: origin, size: CGSize(width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height)))

    let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want an image rotated to 90 degree in any direction, this would may be help:

```
let yourImage = ...
let rotatedImage = UIImage(cgImage: yourImage.cgImage!, scale: 1.0, orientation: .left)
```

Instead of `.left` use `.right` for opposite 90 degree direction.