# iOS Swift3: Programmatically load rotating views or use gif as background image?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, gif

Is there a more 'best practices' way to implement a rotating image on launch screen? I'm currently using the `SwiftGifOrigin` library with a gif to accomplish this, and it's working well. (There's nothing else on the screen other than a tap gesture.) Since gifs aren't natively supported, I feel like what I'm doing must be wrong. I created the gif myself with the `ffmpeg` library and could take some time and implement the graphics programmatically in a carousel, but are there any serious cons to my current implementation?

Comment: Is all the image needs to do rotate or is there some other sort of animation that needs to happen?

Comment: Just rotate. No other animation.

Comment: I was able to load gif in image view using below link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919620/how-to-load-gif-image-in-swift

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using a GIF for this, due to its limited color capabilities and high disk space usage. Simply animate a rotation transform for a UIImageView. [Here is a question about that.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31478630/3151675)