# How to rotate image in landscape and portrait in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, landscape-portrait

In my application in working in portrait mode only. But application having one functionality which is Gallery. In Gallery ,user can view images and i want to rotate image in landscape and portrait mode . 
How can achieve this functionality in iOS.

Comment: This might help - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667565/how-to-rotate-an-image-90-degrees-on-ios

Answer (score 2):

You can rotate your image as in the Imageview by this

```
self.imageview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 90 / 180.0);//90 as in 90 degree
```

Comment: this code where we can  wrote ?

Comment: When you want to rotate the imageview?

Answer (score 0):

```
myImage.center = CGPointMake(0, 0);    
myImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation([degreesToRadians:imageRotationFix]);
```