# How to set the rotation angle of the images in ImageView in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am working with Xamarin.iOS and now I want to rotate the image 90 degrees in ImageView when I click button.I found a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667565/how-to-rotate-an-image-90-degrees-on-ios/11667808#11667808).But it wrote in OC and Swift.How to implement it in C#?I couldn't find method such as `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to refer the following code

```
public UIImage RotateImage(UIImage image, float degree)
{
  float Radians = degree * (float)Math.PI / 180;

  UIView view = new UIView(frame: new CGRect(0, 0, image.Size.Width, image.Size.Height));
  CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation(Radians);
  view.Transform = t;
  CGSize size = view.Frame.Size;

  UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(size);
  CGContext context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();

  context.TranslateCTM(size.Width/2, size.Height/2);
  context.RotateCTM(Radians);
  context.ScaleCTM(1, -1);

  context.DrawImage(new CGRect(-image.Size.Width/2, -image.Size.Height/2, image.Size.Width, image.Size.Height), image.CGImage);

  UIImage imageCopy = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

  return imageCopy;
}
```

Then you can reset the image of UIImageView.
Here is [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49652589/rotate-uiimage-in-xamarin-ios) you can refer .

Comment: It works ! Thank you lucas. You and your colleagues saved me from time to time.

Comment: You are welcome .Happy coding:)

Comment: Not very happy .I've been working 30 hours overtime without sleep.

Answer (score 2):

in Xamarin it's [CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/CoreGraphics.CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation/)

```
using CoreGraphics;

// 1.5708 is 90 degrees in Radians
myImageView.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation(1.5708f);
```

Comment: Thanks! Jason. But I just want to rotation the image and reset the image of imageview.