# Cant get AVFoundation to have proper orientation

Tags: ios, uiimage, avfoundation

I am almost bald after pulling so much hair trying to figure this thing out. I am trying to snap a photo with avFoundation and the orientation is almost always messed up. I have the following function in my ViewWillAppear to capture device orientation:

```
- (void)deviceOrientationDidChange { 
  UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

  if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)
    orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;
  else if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
  // AVCapture and UIDevice have opposite meanings for landscape left and right (AVCapture orientation is the same as UIInterfaceOrientation)
  else if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;
  else if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft;

// Ignore device orientations for which there is no corresponding still image orientation (e.g. UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp)
}
```

This code seems to work fine and captures the proper orientation. I then run the following code to generate the image:

```
    [myConnection setVideoOrientation:self.orientation];
    //THIS IS THE CORRECT ORIENTATION
    NSLog(@"ORIENTATION %d",myConnection.videoOrientation);

[self.stillOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:myConnection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
 {
         if (imageSampleBuffer != nil) {
         NSData *jpeg = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer]; //jpeg image in binary format

         UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:jpeg];

         NSLog(@"IMAGE ORIENTATION: %d", image.imageOrientation);

         postProcessingBlock(image, mutable);

         [mutable release];
         [image release];
     }
     else {
         NSLog(@"AVCapture ERROR:%@", [error localizedDescription]);
     }
 }];
```

When I take a photo in portrait mode using the back camera (button down) my Log shows:

```
ORIENTATION 1
IMAGE ORIENTATION 3
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is it showing me the wrong orientation?

Thanks!

Comment: I used an0's solution from this SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427656/ios-uiimagepickercontroller-result-image-orientation-after-upload/10611036#10611036

Comment: This wont work, it has the wrong orientation saved on the image, thinking that the image should be rotated even when it shouldnt

Comment: I am facing the same problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you figured this out, but you're not doing anything wrong. What is important to note is that `AVCaptureVideoOrientation` and `UIImageOrientation` actually refer to different directions!

`UIImageOrientationUp` actually refers to the device in landscape mode with the volume controls pointed down toward the ground. So `UIImageOrientationLeft` is the correct orientation for a portrait photo with the power button pointed toward the sky.