# Video orientation converted from Portrait to Landscape after uploading to server : iPhone camera

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have captured a video in portrait mode from my application. When I uploaded the same and checked on server, the video was converted to Landscape automatically.

I am using folowing code to start capturing the video

```
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

picker.videoMaximumDuration = 3.0;

picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;  

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

Please advice, I was having same issue while taking image from camera, for which I got help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427656/ios-uiimagepickercontroller-result-image-orientation-after-upload/5427890#5427890) post but for video I am not getting any proper idea.