# Is there a way when you take a picture on iOS7 to not have it flip horizontally using code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, camera

I am wondering if this is actually possible to do. I know I can flip an UIImageView, but the camera on iOS 7 shows the picture flipped horizontally before you select it to display in a uiimageview. Is there any way around this annoyance? If there is please let me know. This can be very annoying to the user as they might not know any better.
Edit:here is my code.

```
        UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        [imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    }

    // image picker needs a delegate,
    [imagePickerController setDelegate:self];

    // Place image picker on the screen
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
```

Comment: I think I can help but need more details - are you using a UIImagePickerController or have you created your own camera capture instance?

Comment: uiimagepickercontroller I will update with some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot *easily* do it, according to [Apple's UIImagePickerClass Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007070-CH3-DontLinkElementID_1):

> Important: The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified, with one exception. You can assign a custom view to the cameraOverlayView property and use that view to present additional information or manage the interactions between the camera interface and your code.

This means that if you want to mess with the orientation, you are going to need to create your own camera controller and handle it all yourself. Check out [this stack overflow question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427656/ios-uiimagepickercontroller-result-image-orientation-after-upload) for more along these lines. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Full Working Example in **Swift**, which answers to the initial question of this post (tested on an iPhone 5c using iOS 8.2):

```
        import UIKit

        class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate {

         @IBOutlet var myUIImageView: UIImageView!

         var myUIImagePickerController: UIImagePickerController!

         override func viewDidLoad() {
             super.viewDidLoad()
         }

         override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
             println("viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) method called.")
             super.viewWillAppear(animated)
             NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
         }

         override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
             println("viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) method called.")
             super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
             NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "cameraChanged:", name: "AVCaptureDeviceDidStartRunningNotification", object: nil)
         }

         /* UIImagePickerControllerDelegate Section */
         func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
              if(self.myUIImagePickerController.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera) {
                 self.myUIImageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
              } else {
                 self.myUIImageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
              }
              self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
         }

        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }

        /*
        You can choose to use one of the UIResponder methods:
        touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded etc, in order to detect the touch
        on the UIImageView.
        */
        override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
            let touch: UITouch? = touches.anyObject() as? UITouch
            if (touch?.view == myUIImageView) {
                println("myUIImageView has been tapped by the user.")
                self.takingAPictureUsingTheCamera()
            }
        }

        func takingAPictureUsingTheCamera() {
            self.myUIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
            self.myUIImagePickerController.delegate = self // Set the delegate
            self.myUIImagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
            self.myUIImagePickerController.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice.Front
    //        self.myUIImagePickerController.editing = true
            self.myUIImagePickerController.allowsEditing = true
            self.presentViewController(self.myUIImagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        func cameraChanged(notification: NSNotification) {
             println("cameraChanged(notification: NSNotification) method called.")
             self.myUIImagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
             if(self.myUIImagePickerController.cameraDevice == UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice.Front){
                 self.myUIImagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.myUIImagePickerController.cameraViewTransform, -1, 1)
             }
        }
       }// End class
```