# Image Orientation problems when reloading images

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, image

I making an app that will let the user take pictures and it saves them to the iPhone Documents folder. When they re-open the View Controller it selects that same image and presents it on the screen. However, I am having serious Image Orientation problems. When the image that was taken is landscape it comes out fine but when it loads a portrait image it comes out 90 degree anti-clockwise.

How can I tell it to do nothing if the image is landscape and rotate 90 if portrait?

Could really use some help please, Im new to iOS development.

Thanks in advance!

Incase you need to know below is the code I am using to save and reload the image:

**Save:**

```
void UIImageWriteToFile(UIImage *image, NSString *fileName)
{
NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDirectoryPath = dirPaths[0];
NSString *filePath = [documentDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```

**Load image:**

```
    NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectoryPath = dirPaths[0];

    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@.png", self.fullname.text];

    NSString *filePath = [documentDirectoryPath stringByAppendingString:fileName];
    image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        [self.imageView setImage:image];
```

EDIT:

I have tried using the code from the link below but it doesn't seem to have any effect. I am calling it like this:

```
    image = [self fixOrientation];
```

and the method is as follows:

(UIImage *)fixOrientation {

```
// No-op if the orientation is already correct
if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) return image;

// We need to calculate the proper transformation to make the image upright.
// We do it in 2 steps: Rotate if Left/Right/Down, and then flip if Mirrored.
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

switch (image.imageOrientation) {
    case UIImageOrientationDown:
    case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, image.size.width, image.size.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationLeft:
    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, image.size.width, 0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI_2);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationRight:
    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, image.size.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -M_PI_2);
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationUp:
    case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
        break;
}

switch (image.imageOrientation) {
    case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
    case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, image.size.width, 0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, image.size.height, 0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationUp:
    case UIImageOrientationDown:
    case UIImageOrientationLeft:
    case UIImageOrientationRight:
        break;
}

// Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform
// calculated above.
CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, image.size.width, image.size.height,
                                         CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(image.CGImage), 0,
                                         CGImageGetColorSpace(image.CGImage),
                                         CGImageGetBitmapInfo(image.CGImage));
CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);
switch (image.imageOrientation) {
    case UIImageOrientationLeft:
    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
    case UIImageOrientationRight:
    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
        // Grr...
        CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.height,image.size.width), image.CGImage);
        break;

    default:
        CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height), image.CGImage);
        break;
}

// And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context
CGImageRef cgimg = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
CGContextRelease(ctx);
CGImageRelease(cgimg);
return img;
```

}

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427656/ios-uiimagepickercontroller-result-image-orientation-after-upload

Comment: I have tried using that method in my code and it doesn't make any difference. I don't know why.

Comment: That fixOrientation method is UIImage category and you are using it wrong. Add a parameter there fixOrientationForImage:(UIImage) image or add the category as it says in the linked question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with orientation comes from not saving image metadata (EXIF, etc) where the orientation information is stored.
PNG files don't store such metadata. JPG files do.

Change your `UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)` to `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);` 
Also change the filename so that it has **.jpg** extension.

Answer (score 0):

How to use the fixOrientation:

```
- (UIImage *)fixOrientationForImage:(UIImage*) image {

// No-op if the orientation is already correct
if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) return image;

// We need to calculate the proper transformation to make the image upright.
// We do it in 2 steps: Rotate if Left/Right/Down, and then flip if Mirrored.
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

switch (image.imageOrientation) {
    case UIImageOrientationDown:
    case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, image.size.width, image.size.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationLeft:
    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, image.size.width, 0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI_2);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationRight:
    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, image.size.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -M_PI_2);
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationUp:
    case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
        break;
}

switch (image.imageOrientation) {
    case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
    case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, image.size.width, 0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, image.size.height, 0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationUp:
    case UIImageOrientationDown:
    case UIImageOrientationLeft:
    case UIImageOrientationRight:
        break;
}

// Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform
// calculated above.
CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, image.size.width, image.size.height,
                                         CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(image.CGImage), 0,
                                         CGImageGetColorSpace(image.CGImage),
                                         CGImageGetBitmapInfo(image.CGImage));
CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);
switch (image.imageOrientation) {
    case UIImageOrientationLeft:
    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
    case UIImageOrientationRight:
    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
        // Grr...
        CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.height,image.size.width), image.CGImage);
        break;

    default:
        CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height), image.CGImage);
        break;
}

// And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context
CGImageRef cgimg = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
CGContextRelease(ctx);
CGImageRelease(cgimg);
return img;
```

}

**image = [self fixOrientationForImage:image];**

Comment: It seems to think that the image rotated 90 degrees anticlockwise is UIImageOrientationUP, so it does nothing because it thinks its correct.