# UIImagePickerController camera automatically converts image to portraitup

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, uiimageorientation

I have called a `UIImagePickerController` to take a photo but every time I take a photo, the camera automatically convert the image to portrait up although I want to take the image in the orientation it was taken.

In the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method, the returned image has the orientation `UIImageOrientationUp` every time.

In my parent controller, I have the following code:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rotate the UIImage to display properly when uploaded, you can use a category like this:

**UIImage+fixOrientation.h**

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427656/ios-uiimagepickercontroller-result-image-orientation-after-upload)