# iOS how to adjust image and mask (either image or mask anyone too zoom in to adjust not both at sametime )

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, mask

I am doing an app where I will take the picture from camera or camera roll and masking with mask image but how i can  adjust image or mask ? i tried scrollview for  zoom in and out and pinch gesture ?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // for zoomin
    [self.imageview setImage:imageView.image];
    [self.scrollView setMaximumZoomScale:5.0f];
    [self.scrollView setClipsToBounds:YES];


    // for drag
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinch=[[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self     action:@selector(pinched:)];
    [self.imageview addGestureRecognizer:pinch];

}


- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.imageview;
}

- (void)pinched:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.scale >1.0f && sender.scale < 2.5f) {
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(sender.scale, sender.scale);
        imageView.transform = transform;
     }
 }

-(IBAction)camera:(id)sender {
    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker.delegate = self;

    [picker setSourceType:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)];
    [self presentViewController:picker1 animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)photoPicker     didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    img = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [self.imageview setImage:img];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
  - (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *) image withMask:(UIImage *) mask
{
CGImageRef imageReference = image.CGImage;
CGImageRef maskReference = mask.CGImage;

CGImageRef imageMask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskReference),
                                         CGImageGetHeight(maskReference),
                                         CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskReference),
                                         CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskReference),
                                         CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskReference),
                                         CGImageGetDataProvider(maskReference),
                                         NULL, // Decode is null
                                         YES // Should interpolate
                                         );

CGImageRef maskedReference = CGImageCreateWithMask(imageReference, imageMask);
CGImageRelease(imageMask);

UIImage *maskedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:maskedReference];
CGImageRelease(maskedReference);

return maskedImage;
```

}

```
- (IBAction)mask:(id)sender {

    self.imageview.image = [self maskImage:img withMask:[UIImage imageNamed:@"18.jpg"]];
    [sender addTarget:self
               action:@selector(maskButtonClicked:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Comment: You need to provide your `maskImage:WithMask:` method. The problem is most likely in there.

Comment: Read my above comment, we can't help you without the seeing problematic code.

Comment: i did that one can u check my above code please

Answer (score 1):

You are losing orientation data when converting to and from a `CGImageRef`.

Instead of `imageWithCGImage:`, use this:

```
[UIImage imageWithCGImage:maskedReference scale:image.scale orientation:image.imageOrientation];
```

**edit**

The mask is also ignoring the image orientation, so the simplest approach is probably just to normalize the image orientation before doing anything to it. [See this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427656/ios-uiimagepickercontroller-result-image-orientation-after-upload/5427890#5427890).

After you get the image but before you begin to mask it, fix its orientation with this:

```
- (UIImage *)normalizedImage:(UIImage *)inputImage 
{
    if (inputImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) return inputImage; 

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(inputImage.size, NO, inputImage.scale);
    [inputImage drawInRect:(CGRect){0, 0, inputImage.size}];
    UIImage *normalizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return normalizedImage;
}
```

Comment: now mask is going to landscape mode,image is  getting fine,

Comment: trying hard unable to fix it :(

Comment: above  code not taking size into account.. still i am trying if anyone know please help me

Comment: @user3649307 I edited my answer. It was just a typo.

Comment: still same problem,, either image or mask getting landscape when changing the code the code ,,