# CGImageCreateWithImageInRect with UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage doesn't work well

Tags: ios

**Objective**: Get bigger edit image from imagePickerController with correct position.

**Question**: Could anyone please help me to get the image and tell me what my code is wrong? In my investigation, **CGImageCreateWithImageInRect** with **UIImagePickerControllerCropRect** looks weird. But not sure...

**Why**: **info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]** is too small, so I want to use **info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]**.

**Issue**: **croppedImage** in the code returns wrong position edited image.

**Other info**: original image is 90 rotated, so I use **imageRotatedByDegrees**  function found in web, and it works well.

```
class PhotoViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

            let originalImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
            let rotatedOriginalImage = originalImage!.imageRotatedByDegrees(90, flip: false)
            let croppedImage = UIImage(CGImage: CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(rotatedOriginalImage.CGImage, info[UIImagePickerControllerCropRect]!.CGRectValue()))
    }
}


// For rotating UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage
// source: http://blog.ruigomes.me/how-to-rotate-an-uiimage-using-swift/
extension UIImage {
    public func imageRotatedByDegrees(degrees: CGFloat, flip: Bool) -> UIImage {
        let radiansToDegrees: (CGFloat) -> CGFloat = {
            return $0 * (180.0 / CGFloat(M_PI))
        }
        let degreesToRadians: (CGFloat) -> CGFloat = {
            return $0 / 180.0 * CGFloat(M_PI)
        }

        // calculate the size of the rotated view's containing box for our drawing space
        let rotatedViewBox = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: size))
        let t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(degrees));
        rotatedViewBox.transform = t
        let rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size

        // Create the bitmap context
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize)
        let bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        // Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
        CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, rotatedSize.width / 2.0, rotatedSize.height / 2.0);

        //   // Rotate the image context
        CGContextRotateCTM(bitmap, degreesToRadians(degrees));

        // Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
        var yFlip: CGFloat

        if(flip){
            yFlip = CGFloat(-1.0)
        } else {
            yFlip = CGFloat(1.0)
        }

        CGContextScaleCTM(bitmap, yFlip, -1.0)
        CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(-size.width / 2, -size.height / 2, size.width, size.height), CGImage)

        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. The problem was look like the image orientation function has a bug. 
[iOS UIImagePickerController result image orientation after upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427656/ios-uiimagepickercontroller-result-image-orientation-after-upload)

- I should read the code more to understand what the root cause is.