# UIImage orientation issue in Share Extension

Tags: ios, share, uiimageorientation, share-extension

I am trying a Share Extension that iOS provides. Having trouble while getting UIImage from gallery host.

The image is is not in appropriate orientation. Any suggestion how can i get proper image from Photos as host to Share extension.
I am using loadItemForTypeIdentifier of NSItemProvider to get image object. 
Kindly help, thanks in advance.

Comment: I had a image-orientation problem a while back.
This helped me: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427656/ios-uiimagepickercontroller-result-image-orientation-after-upload

Comment: David the solution you have provided is quite helpful, but does category works with extension?

Comment: Check out the second answer by an0. The swift version of that function was working great for me.

Comment: Thanks @DavidSchmoecker your answer does work for me and category too works in Extension thanks a lot :)