# Image rotation issue from camera picked image

Tags: ios, ipad, image-rotation, ios-camera

I am getting image which is captured from camera. And I am uploading that image to server. After I get the same image from server, it is rotated 90 degrees. I searched and tried lot more code. But didn't work. Please guide me.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        // let imgData: NSData = NSData(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation((image), 1.0)!)
        uploadImageToServer(img: image)
    }
```

Comment: Is there any difference if you take the pic portrait or landscape?

Comment: Lots and lots of discussion, answers and sample code related to this out there. What code have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: Check answer posted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/27083555/4646572

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to fix this is to allow editing of photos in the UIImagePickerController:

```
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
```

And in the delegate take the edited image:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    guard let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage else { return }
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```