# Auto rotate image to portrait when I take photo landscape in portrait mode objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3

I take a image portrait but UIImageView show landscape. I want auto rotate image to portrait when I take photo landscape in portrait mode. Please see clip.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S8RQ1yDKvFQ

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried already? what code do you have?

Comment: @Scriptable: Yes, I have tried. I follow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427656/ios-uiimagepickercontroller-result-image-orientation-after-upload/5427890#5427890 and I tried code but it don't change.    

NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(photo);
    photo = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data].CGImage
                                       scale:photo.scale
                                 orientation:photo.imageOrientation];