# iOS Swift 3 Image rotated 90 degrees Left

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

In my app I have a feature to take a picture from `camera` and upload it to server. My problem is that when I'm getting response back from server that image is rotating to 90 degree left side. Here is my tried code:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{
    self.PickerFrom = self.PickerFrom2
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    {
       self.AttachmentImageView.image = pickedImage
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    uploadGalleryImage(image: self.AttachmentImageView.image!)
}

func uploadGalleryImage( image:UIImage)
{
    let imageData: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)! as NSData
    let base64String = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    self.AttachedDocumentURL = "data:image/png;base64,\(base64String)"
}
```

`AttachedDocumentURL` contains base64sting of captured image.

Comment: how the image is saved in server, its stored at 90 degree or stored at normal

Comment: when u take phone in camera, that image have orientation property itself. so, check that and rotation as per that orientation and send to server. lot of code available in net or u can write yourself.

Comment: You can check my ans here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45157225/want-fixed-orientation-but-the-uiimage-autoratate/45157920#45157920

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this (reset you image orientation) before you upload on server

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{
    self.PickerFrom = self.PickerFrom2
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    {
       self.AttachmentImageView.image = pickedImage
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    if let updatedImage = self.AttachmentImageView.image?.updateImageOrientionUpSide() {
      uploadGalleryImage(image: updatedImage)
    } else {
      uploadGalleryImage(image: self.AttachmentImageView.image!)
    }

}

func uploadGalleryImage( image:UIImage)
{
    let imageData: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)! as NSData
    let base64String = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    self.AttachedDocumentURL = "data:image/png;base64,\(base64String)"
}

// Image extension
extension UIImage {

    func updateImageOrientionUpSide() -> UIImage? {
        if self.imageOrientation == .up {
            return self
        }

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, self.scale)
        self.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height))
        if let normalizedImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() {
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            return normalizedImage
        }
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this common function to fix upside image orientation from any.

```
extension UIImage {

    func fixImageOrientation() -> UIImage? {


        if (self.imageOrientation == .up) {
            return self
        }

        var transform: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity


        if ( self.imageOrientation == .left || self.imageOrientation == .leftMirrored ) {
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: self.size.width, y: 0)
            transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2.0))
        } else if ( self.imageOrientation == .right || self.imageOrientation == .rightMirrored ) {
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: self.size.height);
            transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(-Double.pi / 2.0));
        } else if ( self.imageOrientation == .down || self.imageOrientation == .downMirrored ) {
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: self.size.width, y: self.size.height)
            transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi))
        } else if ( self.imageOrientation == .upMirrored || self.imageOrientation == .downMirrored ) {
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: self.size.width, y: 0)
            transform = transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1)
        } else if ( self.imageOrientation == .leftMirrored || self.imageOrientation == .rightMirrored ) {
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: self.size.height, y: 0);
            transform = transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1);
        }


        if let context: CGContext = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(self.size.width), height: Int(self.size.height),
                                       bitsPerComponent: self.cgImage!.bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: 0,
                                       space: self.cgImage!.colorSpace!,
                                       bitmapInfo: self.cgImage!.bitmapInfo.rawValue) {

            context.concatenate(transform)

            if ( self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.left ||
                self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.leftMirrored ||
                self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.right ||
                self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.rightMirrored ) {
                context.draw(self.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: self.size.height,height: self.size.width))
            } else {
                context.draw(self.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: self.size.width,height: self.size.height))
            }

            if let contextImage = context.makeImage() {
                return UIImage(cgImage: contextImage)
            }

        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4.1 compatible.
This extension avoids sending image exif data on the iOS device side.

```
extension UIImage {

    func fixOrientation() -> UIImage? {

        if (imageOrientation == .up) { return self }

        var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity

        switch imageOrientation {
        case .left, .leftMirrored:
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: size.width, y: 0.0)
            transform = transform.rotated(by: .pi / 2.0)
        case .right, .rightMirrored:
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: 0.0, y: size.height)
            transform = transform.rotated(by: -.pi / 2.0)
        case .down, .downMirrored:
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: size.width, y: size.height)
            transform = transform.rotated(by: .pi)
        default:
            break
        }

        switch imageOrientation {
        case .upMirrored, .downMirrored:
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: size.width, y: 0.0)
            transform = transform.scaledBy(x: -1.0, y: 1.0)
        case .leftMirrored, .rightMirrored:
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: size.height, y: 0.0)
            transform = transform.scaledBy(x: -1.0, y: 1.0)
        default:
            break
        }

        guard let cgImg = cgImage else { return nil }

        if let context = CGContext(data: nil,
                                   width: Int(size.width), height: Int(size.height),
                                   bitsPerComponent: cgImg.bitsPerComponent,
                                   bytesPerRow: 0, space: cgImg.colorSpace!,
                                   bitmapInfo: cgImg.bitmapInfo.rawValue) {

            context.concatenate(transform)

            if imageOrientation == .left || imageOrientation == .leftMirrored ||
                imageOrientation == .right || imageOrientation == .rightMirrored {
                context.draw(cgImg, in: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: size.height, height: size.width))
            } else {
                context.draw(cgImg, in: CGRect(x: 0.0 , y: 0.0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
            }

            if let contextImage = context.makeImage() {
                return UIImage(cgImage: contextImage)
            }

        }

        return nil
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: @LonelyNeuron ok, thanks. A simple description was added.