# Image gets rotated when retrieved from file

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I'm modifying some code from [an online lesson on using `UIPickerViewController`](https://appsandbiscuits.com/take-save-and-retrieve-a-photo-ios-13-4312f96793ff).

I'm taking a photo, displaying in a `UIImageView` in my first View Controller, then saving it to file. Then I retrieve it and display it in a `UIImageView` in my second View Controller. The `UIImageView`s are the same size (375 x 315), and use the same settings:

[image]

The first VC looks like this after snapping the picture and hitting the "Use photo" button on the `UIPickerViewController` interface:

[image]

The second VC looks like this after I retrieve the pic (I'm using PNG):

[image]

I've banged around a lot on SO, yet haven't found a solution for iOS. Can someone please point me in the right direction? I can supply any code (which seems unremarkable), but I don't think that's where the problem lies.

Thanks! All Help appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Swift 3 Image rotated 90 degrees Left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45324544/ios-swift-3-image-rotated-90-degrees-left)

Comment: If the dup vote doesn't help, consider using the `UIImage.orientation` property. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/orientation

Comment: Thanks, amigos! Please see my answer below. Don't know if I'd have found what I needed without your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8915809/2671035), which was only a click or two away from the link provided by @ocanal in his comment above. I did have to convert from Obj C to Swift, but it works like magic. Here's the code I added to achieve the correct orientation:

let originalImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)

```
var imageToDisplay: UIImage? = nil
if let anImage = originalImage?.cgImage {
    imageToDisplay = UIImage(cgImage: anImage, scale: originalImage!.scale, orientation: .right)
```