# Why when i do presentModalViewController(MyImagePicker) the orientation is inversed

Tags: ios, delphi, uiview, uiviewcontroller, firemonkey

I m under Delphi tokyo (but not sure if it's matter). it's for an Ios application (Ipad). My application can have only 2 orientations : **portrait** and **upsidedown**. my problem is that when my application is in **upsidedown**, and i do

```
SharedApplication.keyWindow.rootViewController.presentModalViewController(MyImagePicker, True);
```

Then the orientation of the ImagePicker is **inversed** (instead to be upsidedown it's portrait). If i rotate the ipad the orientation of the image picker don't change. When i validate the selection and come back to my app, now the orientation of my app is also inversed (but contrary to the imagepicker i can now  rotate the ipad to change the orientation)

What did i miss and how to correct it ?

Comment: Check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427656/ios-uiimagepickercontroller-result-image-orientation-after-upload

Comment: @Nitish: thanks however my problem is not with the image data, but with the full image picker dialog that is inversed